# Washing machine tub grinding and banging

Tags: washing-machine

I have a Samsung front loader washing machine, from around 2011-2012 model number WF221ANG XAA.

My wife noticed one evening that it was making a lot of noise, so she turned it off and it's been off since to avoid further damage. I wasn't in the house so I didn't hear the noise myself.

The tub spins by hand smoothly about 270 degrees or so, but the remaining 90 degrees has a lot of resistance, kind of a squeaky sound like metal against rubber and kind of shaky, until the last 10 degrees or so where it goes CLUNK, then back into smooth spinning.

I am not at all an expert on washing machines but my guess would be that the bearing is finished.

Any ideas what is causing that ?

Comment: The suspension is loose or broken

Comment: your question asks for an opinion ... that is not allowed here .... please ask about the problem instead

Comment: @jsotola Please elaborate. I think the question is fine the way it is.

Comment: you asked `Should I attempt to repair, pay an expert, or just get a new machine as it's already quite old`

Answer (score 3):

The tub mounting bracket (called the "spider") is broken. This is a common problem with front loaders.

As far as I know, no manufacturer sells this part separately. It is included in the drum assembly, usually priced at more than half the cost of a new machine.